# Is narginchk(x,x) redundant for a function which does not accept varargin?

Tags: matlab

I am new to the MATLAB world. In looking around, I have come across a function which looks like

```
function out = f(x, y, z)
    narginchk(3, 3);    
    out = x * y * z; % contents simplified for illustration purpose
end
```

I can't say with confidence that the "narginchk" is redundant, but it sure looks like that to me. Can someone tell me if there is any legitimate reason to put this in if the function signature alreadys requires (here) exactly 3 inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: Im not an expert, but it seems is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even without `varargin`, the caller can omit arguments.  So `narginchk` is needed to catch that.

`varargin` is mostly used for tagged options, where you can't give a meaningful name to the parameters based solely on position.

Here's a small demonstration that MATLAB makes all arguments optional by default:

```
function out = f(x, y, z)
    narginchk(2, 3);
    if nargin < 3
        z = 17;
    end
    out = x * y * z;
end

>> f(1,2)

ans =

    34
```

Part of the confusion is the wording of the error message you're getting.  MATLAB says "Not enough input arguments."  What it means is "The function used an argument that was missing."

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. Can you give me an example of "the caller omitting arguments"?

Comment: MATLAB will allow `result = f(5);`  You have the idea that "the function signature requires three arguments", but in MATLAB that isn't true.

Comment: Really? If I copy the snippet above into MATLAB, and remove the narginchk, it still (rightly to me) complains that "Error using f (line 3)\nNot enough input arguments." if I call f(1, 2)

Comment: @Derek: You got that error only when the omitted argument was used (line 3).  Imagine how confusing that would be if the function was 600 lines long and the first use of the missing argument was on line 471.  You also can change missing arguments to default values if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I did go off to read a bit more about how optional arguments are used in functions, and can see why this is in fact non redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In this form, it is redundant. However, different errors are thrown if not enough arguments are passed to the function, depending on whether you use `narginchk` or not.
If you try to execute `f(1,2)` without `narginchk(3,3)`, the error thrown is of type `MATLAB:minrhs`. If `narginchk(3,3)` is in place, then the error thrown is of type `MATLAB:narginchk:notEnoughInputs`.
However, if you try to use too many arguments, e.g. `f(1,2,3,4)`, the error always is of type `MATLAB:TooManyInputs`

So using `narginchk` for functions with a fixed number of parameters in a way makes a difference, but I don't think that there are many practical uses for the different types of errors you can get.

Comment: Thanks magnetometer. This is fully informative. Accepted!

Comment: Your answer is self contradictory.  If MATLAB checked the number of arguments on call, the `narginchk` line wouldn't be reached.  But it is...

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm just documenting Matlab's behaviour, not interpreting it. I tested it in Matlab 2013a and this is what I got.

Comment: Your test wasn't detailed enough to reveal the true behavior, though.